# Logo for website

Tags: website-design, logo

I am new to web design, what is the best way to save logo for web?
I am exporting as png and logo shows up too small on website. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: file format doesn't have anything to do with the size. The size is about a) pixel dimensions of your image and b) that your HTML and CSS are set to show it at the size you want. We can't be of much more help without seeing your image and markup.

Comment: Thank you. I need to increase pixels then. Here is the logo, left top. You can barely see it. :)http://tanja-lippert.format.com/home

Comment: Export/save at a larger size, then use that size in the HTML/CSS.

Comment: That image is 135 × 9. Which is really small. So, yes, you need to increase the pixel dimensions of that image. (Perhaps double it to 18 x 270)

Comment: Thank you. I am Export/png at 300 ppi and it is still small. :( I know this is a simple thing to do, but all new to me. I'm also trying to export it from illustrator to look as sharp as possible.

Comment: You want the absolute pixel size here, not PPI. PPI (pixels per inch) is the _density_ of pixels, not the measurements of the image in pixels.

Comment: So Janus, how should I export, as png, jpg, save as web? Where do I select this absolute pixel size?

Comment: @Gorete Your image is fine. In your CSS you have the image restricted to a max-height of 110px. With this restriction in place, the browser will re-size the image proportionally. max-height overrides width.  If you are unsure where to take it from there, I suggest you move this question to stackoverflow. Otherwise, take a look at my answer which addresses your original question.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the community too. Don't forget to accept an answer if you feel that it has answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not too complex of a logo, you should look into re-creating it as a vector and exporting it as a SVG. Not only are SVG's supported in all modern browsers, but it is the ideal image format for non-complex geometric graphics used on the web since it can scale without quality loss. This is especially useful when creating a [responsive website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

A vector copy of the logo is something that you should have anyways in case it is needed in the future for print, larger display, etc.

If SVG isnt your thing, PNG is the next best choice for logos (assuming that it is not too complex). The general rule of thumb is, for graphics under 256 colors go with PNG-8, otherwise use PNG-24.

Whichever format you choose to go with, it is import that that you compress the image before deploying to the website. Uncompressed images can lead to huge file sizes which can take a toll on your page speed.

I reccommend that you read this extremely helpful [Image Optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization) Guide by Google.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the png file in a separate browser window you can see that the logo actually is as big as you might have intended. However, the picture as a whole is much bigger and contains plenty of white space around the logo. Since the big png including the white space is fit into the small space on your homepage the logo gets very small. What you need to do is to crop the picture so the white space is removed.